SQL query not show data correctly
SELECT loan_applications.province_id AS province_id,
loan_applications.branch AS branch,
loans.id AS loanid,
loans.client_id,
loans.loan_application_id,
loan_applications.disbursement_date AS disbdate,
loan_applications.disbursed_amount AS disbamt,
loans.term_period,
loan_applications.current_loan_place AS loancycle,
loans.last_repayment_date AS maturitydate,
clients.dob,
JSON_EXTRACT (loan_question_data.input_data, '$.gender') AS gender,
JSON_EXTRACT (loan_question_data.input_data, '$.martial_status') AS martial,
JSON_EXTRACT (loan_question_data.input_data, '$.education') AS education,
loan_repayment_schedule.status,
loan_repayment_schedule.remain_balance,
loan_repayment_schedule.period,
loan_repayment_schedule.repayment_date,
loan_repayment_schedule.updated_at
FROM
loans
JOIN loan_applications ON loans.loan_application_id = loan_applications.id
JOIN clients ON loans.client_id = clients.id
JOIN loan_question_data ON loan_applications.id = loan_question_data.id
JOIN loan_repayment_schedule ON loans.id = loan_repayment_schedule.loan_id
WHERE
loans.created_at BETWEEN '2024-05-01' AND '2024-05-31';

This current query that joined loans table and loan_repayment_schedule table.The result is -




loan_id
Status
Remain_balance
Updated_At




4339
paid
7000.00
2024-05-11 07:58:21


4339
unpaid
5303.56
2024-05-01 00:28:29


4339
unpaid
3582.03
2024-05-01 00:28:29


4339
unpaid
1838.55
2024-05-01 00:28:29



but in the loan_repayment_schedule table, the status and repayment date is not same.




loan_id
Status
Remain_balance
Updated_At




4339
paid
7000.00
2024-05-11 07:58:21


4339
paid
5303.56
2024-05-26 01:31:15


4339
paid
3582.03
2024-06-11 18:34:38


4339
unpaid
1838.55
2024-05-01 00:28:29



How can I correct these data ? I match with loan_id.

Make it easy to assist you - simplify! Provide a complete [mcve].

I would say, since the data is not the same, that you're looking at different rows of the loan_repayment_schedule table.

If the problem is with data, then please provide sample data for all involved tables, expected and actual results received. Otherwise it is nearly impossible for us to help with your question!

@Shadow
Data from Query
4339 paid 7000.00 1 2024-05-10 2024-05-11 07:58:21
4339 unpaid 5303.56 2  2024-05-01 00:28:29
4339 unpaid 3582.03 3  2024-05-01 00:28:29
4339 unpaid 1838.55 4  2024-05-01 00:28:29
Data from loan_repayment_schedule table
4339 paid 2024-05-10 7000.00 2024-05-11 07:58:21
4339 paid 2024-05-25 5269.04 2024-05-26 01:31:15
4339 paid 2024-06-10 3546.99 2024-06-11 18:34:38
4339 unpaid  1838.55 2024-05-01 00:28:29
The query result show the last 3 row duplicate. The updated_at time is same.

Please edit the question and add your data as tables there. Please add column(s) uniquely idntifying the rows so that we know what matches with what.

@Shadow Thank you for your support.
I edit result image. Please kindly help.

Please do not edit images, add the data as tables.

@Shadow Done bro !

The two data sets do not match. We cannot reconcile the two datasets. Your example is not a minimal verifiable example as jarlh commented. We cannot tell you why the two datasets are different, unless you provide context.

@Shadow Thank you bro. I think it's not about query bcoz the data is correct when I run at phpadmin and the data is not correct when I run on DBeaver. It's strange. Do you have any suggestion ?

sounds like DBeaver is connecting to a different database than phpadmin?  or possibly loan_repayment_schedule is some kind of complex view and there's a bug in the view definition that makes it come out differently.
